# Improving Performance of SQL Server Query - Static Values in Filter vs Joining to Other Table for Values

Tags: sql-server, optimization

I have very simple logic to extract data from two tables, actually two views in SQL Server.

One way of doing this is (#1 to extract specific ID values from table A; #2 to take those values from query 1 and query for records having those same IDs from table B).  When i do this, it takes less than a second for query #1 to complete, and less than 3 seconds for query #2 to complete)

The preferred way is to either join the two tables above, or have the first table look in the second table via SQL (i.e. select * from table B where ID in (select ID from table A where .....).  This preferred way takes too long - let's say over 5 minutes, and it's not acceptable.

I have read only access.  Is there another way to get the preferred way to run and complete in a reasonable amount of time?

Tried joining two tables, tried setting second query as the filter to the first query

Comment: Is the database read only, or just your access? If the latter, then talk to your DBA; it's their job to performance time and they can help you write *good* queries. If the former is it a replica? If so, then perhaps you should ensure your using SQL Server 2022, which now has Query Store available on read-only replicas.

Comment: It's very hard to answer this type of question without at a minimum: the query, the table *and index* definitions, and please share the query plan via https://pastetheplan.com. This question is not answerable otherwise

Comment: Do you have access to create a stored procedure - if not, do you have access to the source code for both views?  I would recommend getting that source code and seeing if it is possible to write a single query to pull the data as needed instead of relying on joining two separate views.

Answer (score 0):

You can try your query that way:

```sql
select *
from table B
where
    exists (
        select 1
          from A
         where A.ID = B.ID
    )
```

But all attempts here are not more than guessing.

Query "speed" depends heavily on DBMS, its optimization, table structure, indexes and so on.

Go to you DBA, ask them to get query plan and help you optimize it.